# Is there a software similar to sudo but to drop capabilities while creating a new process?

Tags: linux

I am looking for a software - preferably packaged - which allows me to execute a program with fewer capabilities than a full superuser context would grant. Yes, this is mainly about *dropping* capabilities.

[Capabilities](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) are a way to hand out superuser rights "in slices". And while [capsh](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/capsh.1.html) fits the bill, it does not provide a way to declare a policy similar to what `/etc/sudoers` allows.

So: is there a tool which can drop capabilities and is configurable via files?

Comment: What do you mean by "configurable via files"? Sooner or later, everything is in a file. I would create a new user with just the rights you want and then use `runuser -l  username -c 'command'`

Comment: @ThomasWeller could you explain how exactly I can configure that new user to have a limited set of capabilities as opposed to the - somewhat binary - superuser vs. unprivileged scheme? Thanks. I'm simply not aware of a method like this and was hoping that capabilities would be a nice way of handing out particular privileges in small doses ... smaller doses than allowing user X to run certain commands as full superuser. Configurable via files should be clear from drawing the line to `sudoers`, no?

Answer (score 1):

`firejail` might be the tool that fits your need. It was initially written for Firefox but now handle other software.

See https://firejail.wordpress.com/

It says:

> Firejail is a SUID program that reduces the risk of security breaches
>   by restricting the running environment of untrusted applications using
>   Linux namespaces and seccomp-bpf. It allows a process and all its
>   descendants to have their own private view of the globally shared
>   kernel resources, such as the network stack, process table, mount
>   table.

You can find examples of their default profile, to restrict things per application at https://github.com/netblue30/firejail/tree/master/etc/profile-a-l and https://github.com/netblue30/firejail/tree/master/etc/profile-m-z

The documentation explains how to write your own custom profiles.

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of firejail, in fact I am using it already for GUI stuff, but I hadn't considered it for this particular purpose. I'll see whether this nudges me in the right direction. Until then, have an upvote.